# Connect Laravel Sail App to Local MySql Server

Tags: docker-compose, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel Sail app that was installed without the MySql service, since I want to use the MySql server on the local mac where the application is installed.

How do I do this?  Presumably I need to modify the docker-compose file to redirect port 3306, but how?  (I tried binding 3306:3306 in docker-compose beneath the line assigning port 80, but it tells me the port is already taken).

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the answer is quite simple.  Use `host.docker.internal` as the hostname when inside the container.

Comment: Forgot all about this. Thanks man!